# Android: Is there a way to use the same fragment twice on a page?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a fragment that I initialize in a view pager that is used for chat. I need that same fragment to exist in a different part of the page when the screen goes into landscape.

I tried to add the fragment to the view where I need it but I got this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I would just create two instances of the fragment where I need it but the chats get out of sync.

Does anyone know how to reuse an instance of a fragment in two places?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must have two separate instances of your fragment. You cannot reuse - that's pretty bad idea